# missing Builds in iTunesConnect

Tags: xamarin.ios, testflight

I have uploaded two new versions as I always do. But the areas with the versions are empty.

Can anybody help?

[missing Builds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIoKE.png)

Answer (score 0):

1st id confirm the browser your on, I seem to get on better with Chrome on iTC.

Processing time can cause them to not appear either, some times it takes a little while to populate.

Let me know how you get on